# Oracle SQL regexp_substr

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a query which fetches value matching the pattern, I want it to fetch all prefvalue instead of only CEROTG

```
SELECT regexp_substr('prefvalue:CEROTG-2 prefvalue:CEROTG prefvalue:CEROTG_1', 'prefvalue:([[:alnum:]_]+)') as Result from dual
```

Current Output

```
prefvalue:CEROTG
```

Expected Output

```
prefvalue:CEROTG
prefvalue:CEROTG-2
prefvalue:CEROTG_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a recursive query:

```
with 
    data as (select 'prefvalue:CEROTG-2 prefvalue:CEROTG prefvalue:CEROTG_1' str from dual),
    cte(str, res, lvl) as (
        select str, regexp_substr(str, 'prefvalue:([[:alnum:]_-]+)'), 1 lvl from data
        union all
        select str, regexp_substr(str, 'prefvalue:([[:alnum:]_-]+)', 1, lvl + 1), lvl + 1 
        from cte 
        where lvl < regexp_count(str, 'prefvalue:([[:alnum:]_-]+)')
    )
select res from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=415ce87130fb7641aec8c25028ea482f)**:

```
| RES                |
| :----------------- |
| prefvalue:CEROTG-2 |
| prefvalue:CEROTG   |
| prefvalue:CEROTG_1 |
```

Comment: actually my query is like this 

SELECT regexp_substr(entry_data,'prefvalue:([[:alnum:]_]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS VALUE_STR
FROM   v500.prefdir_entrydata 
WHERE  dist_name_short = 
'prefentry=imagerepository,prefgroup=cdi_globals,prefgroup=component,prefgroup=system,prefcontext=default,prefroot=prefroot'

Comment: can't we make it more dynamic in regex pattern itself by giving look for no of occurrence's or so

Comment: @niku: regexp functions are scalar functions, they cannot generate new rows, so you need some kind of iterative process (hence the recursive CTE, or `connect by`, which are the same in essence). You can move your existing query to the `data` cte.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string functions in a recursive subquery-factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc ( entry_data, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT entry_data, 1, INSTR( entry_data, ' ', 1 )
  FROM   prefdir_entrydata
UNION ALL
  SELECT entry_data, end_pos + 1, INSTR( entry_data, ' ', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT CASE end_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( entry_data, start_pos )
       ELSE SUBSTR( entry_data, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
       END AS value
FROM   rsqfc
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE prefdir_entrydata ( entry_data ) AS
SELECT 'prefvalue:CEROTG-2 prefvalue:CEROTG prefvalue:CEROTG_1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE              |
> | :----------------- |
> | prefvalue:CEROTG-2 |
> | prefvalue:CEROTG   |
> | prefvalue:CEROTG_1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1663a956f33bf1a7e92f6549e0353d8)*

---

An example that handles multiple input rows is:

```sql
WITH rsqfc ( id, entry_data, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT id, entry_data, 1, INSTR( entry_data, ' ', 1 )
  FROM   prefdir_entrydata
  WHERE  dist_name_short = 'prefentry=imagerepository,prefgroup=cdi_globals,prefgroup=component,prefgroup=system,prefcontext=default,prefroot=prefroot'
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, entry_data, end_pos + 1, INSTR( entry_data, ' ', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT id,
       CASE end_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( entry_data, start_pos )
       ELSE SUBSTR( entry_data, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
       END AS value
FROM   rsqfc
ORDER BY id, start_pos
```

Which, for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE prefdir_entrydata ( id, entry_data, dist_name_short ) AS
SELECT 1,
       'prefvalue:CEROTG-2 prefvalue:CEROTG prefvalue:CEROTG_1',
       'prefentry=imagerepository,prefgroup=cdi_globals,prefgroup=component,prefgroup=system,prefcontext=default,prefroot=prefroot'
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       'prefvalue:CEROTG-2a prefvalue:CEROTG_1v2',
       'prefentry=imagerepository,prefgroup=cdi_globals,prefgroup=component,prefgroup=system,prefcontext=default,prefroot=prefroot'
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | VALUE               
> -: | :-------------------
>  1 | prefvalue:CEROTG-2  
>  1 | prefvalue:CEROTG    
>  1 | prefvalue:CEROTG_1  
>  2 | prefvalue:CEROTG-2a 
>  2 | prefvalue:CEROTG_1v2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=53471ec0ed99788fa6972dfe8f6d6f4c)*

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tbl(DATA) AS (
  SELECT 'prefvalue:CEROTG-2 prefvalue:CEROTG prefvalue:CEROTG_1'
  FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) ELEMENT
FROM tbl
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(DATA, ' ')+1; 

ELEMENT                                               
------------------------------------------------------
prefvalue:CEROTG-2                                    
prefvalue:CEROTG                                      
prefvalue:CEROTG_1                                    

3 rows selected.
```